# Implementing Domain Name System

Tags: c, dns

I am working on a project in embedded c.The project is the electronic Cash Register.In this

project i need to send the sale data through *gprs* on to a server our own made application

in C#. Now i have to change the ip of the server on the machine side because of dynamic ip.i

want to implement **dns** in my Machine so that idont need to change ip every time.plz anyone

in this.And what changes does i need to do on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your IP dynamic because of your ISP setup?

If so i'd say the easiest way would be to sign up to someone like [no-ip.com](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html). their free service will give you a url and an application to install on your server. When your ip changes on the server the application updates their records so the url is routed to the correct IP. Basically in short, going to the url there give you will alway go to your server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ ASH Burlaczenko Sir i have received a url and an application from no-ip.com.now what changes should i made on the machine side i.e how to machine will know about the url

Comment: Where ever the ip is that you were going to have to change orignally, replace that with the url.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you want or need to implement a DNS server (and this is a very complex task, because DNS is a complex protocol, and you need to think of security issues). You only need to use a library call (like `getaddrinfo`and friends) which use eventually DNS to transform a host name to an IP address or vice versa.